Fundamental group of $\mathbb{R}P^2$ using rectangle CW structure
Look at the two CW decompositions for the real projective plane:

Two vertices, two edges, where the edges are identified with opposite direction. Computing $\pi_1$ in this way, gives the group generated by the $1$-skeleton, i.e. the one edge, call it $a$, and the relation $a^2 = 1$, which is indeed $\mathbb{Z}_2$, $\pi_1$ of the real projective plane.
However, if we take the CW decomposition here - a square with two edges identified, we get a group generated by two generators $a,b$, and the relation we get by going over the boundary is $abab=1$. This group is not $\mathbb{Z}_2$. Where is the mistake?


I think $a$ and $b$ do not generate the fundamental group, because in the CW structure they are not loops, but paths forwards and backwards between two 0-cells ("half-loops"). Instead $ab$ generates the fundamental group, so quotienting by the relation $abab = 1$ does yield $\mathbb{Z}_2$. I'll leave it to someone else to articulate this better. (You can convince yourself that there should be two 0-cells by quotienting the corners of the square by the relation "lie on the head or tail of the same arrow".)

Thank you. I think it answers my question, in case you want to post it as an answer.
